# Java - Convert Image to Icon/ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, imageicon

I have an Image object that I would like to convert to an Icon or ImageIcon to add to a JTextPane. How would I go about doing this? 
(this is in JAVA)

clarification: my "Image" is an instance of the Image Object, not a File.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

What's wrong with [`new ImageIcon(Image)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.awt.Image%29)?

```
Image img = ...
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the image to your JTextPane document:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("myImage.jpg"));

StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
StyledDocument document = new DefaultStyledDocument(context);

Style labelStyle = context.getStyle(StyleContext.DEFAULT_STYLE);

Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
StyleConstants.setComponent(labelStyle, label);

document.insertString(document.getLength(), "Ignored", labelStyle);

JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Toolkit t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

Image i = t.getImage("icon.gif");

setIconImage(i);
```

Comment: that wouldnt work, since i have an Image Object not an image File. I would have to save the image to a file, then read the file for that to work

Comment: Write it to a file by converting it into bytes

Comment: i may have to do that, but that would be a very roundabout way

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding here, unless you're actually advising to take the Image, write it out as binary, and read it back in to end up with another image instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon icon=null; 

ImageIcon imageicon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Winter.jpg");

if (imageicon != null) {

    if (imageicon.getIconWidth() > 60) {
        System.out.println(jLabel1.getWidth());
        icon = new ImageIcon(imageicon.getImage().getScaledInstance(26, -1, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
    } else {
        icon = imageicon;
}

jLabel1.setIcon((Icon) icon);
```

Answer (score 0):

convert image to icon, for example set Icon to a jLable in netbeans, i use below code to make it true:

```
JLabelname.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/slip/images/null_phot.png")));
```